# Access/SQL Query Performance - Creating a unique list based on multiple data sources

Tags: performance, t-sql, ms-access

The objective of this post is to improve the performance of the following query.

The query essentially compiles a list of all unique [Asset] that appear throughout multiple data sources and appends it to another table.

See Sample Tables Below

```
[Import - Assets]       Asset   Description   Type      Unit
                         P1        Water      Pump       U1
                         P2         Oil       Mix        U2

[Import - BOM]          Asset      Comp    Description   Qty
                         P1         10          X         1
                         P1         11          Y         1
                         M1         20          Z         1

[Import - WO]            WO        Asset   Description   Cost
                         1          P2          x         10
                         2          P2          y         20
                         3          M2          z         22

[Desired Output]        Asset   Description   Type       Unit
                         P1        Water      Pump        U1
                         P2         Oil        Mix        U2
                         M1
                         M2
```

This query and others with similar functions run extremely slow. I believe the performance issues are a result of the large checks in the WHERE portions (each table can have upwards of 10k records).

It may be the case that the "Import" tables have duplicate [Asset] records that are not removed through the UNION function because they are not identical throughout the other fields. Due to my suspicions, I would like to first remove duplicate [Asset] in each table before checking it against the other tables. For example, only check record 1 & 3 of BOM against records 1 & 3 of WO, rather than all to all.

```
INSERT INTO [Data - Assets]
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT "Assets" AS [Source], *
FROM [Import - Assets]

UNION 

SELECT "BOM", [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM [Import - BOM]
WHERE [Asset] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Asset] FROM [Import - Assets])

UNION SELECT "WO", [Asset], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM [Import - WO]
WHERE [Asset] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Asset] FROM [Import - Assets])
AND [Asset] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Asset] FROM [Import - BOM])

ORDER BY [Source], [Asset]
) ;
```

It should be noted that aside from the initial [Import - Assets] table, the source of the additional records does not particularly matter.

I am very new to SQL. Any help in improving performance and instilling good habits is greatly appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Try the following changes 1) change to union all 2) change where clause to left join b on .. where b is null 3) remove the order by 4) remove the select * you wrap the query with

Comment: Can you elaborate on 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the "NOT IN"'s are killing your query.
Just do a full union and then make it a subquery to only include the extra values from the Asset table.

```
SELECT x.Asset, MAX(x.Description) Description, MAX(x.Type) Type, MAX(x.Unit) Unit
FROM
(SELECT Asset, Description, Type, Unit FROM [Import - Assets]
UNION SELECT Asset, NULL Description, NULL Type, NULL Unit FROM [Import - BOM]
UNION SELECT Asset, NULL Description, NULL Type, NULL Unit FROM [Import - WO]) x
GROUP BY x.Asset
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be AS before each field name?

Comment: as is optional keyword